# Integrating Unity and Eclipse

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've struggled integrating Unity and Android in Eclipse.
I was following [these steps.][1]

Importing the unity project as a library, compiler tells me there is no a file in my Android project: com.unity3d.player.unityplayerproxyactivity.jar

Error: The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Work\Unity Projects\Tutorials\UnityProjectLibaray\StagingArea\bin\com.unity3d.player.unityplayerproxyactivity.jar'

Help me. I would appreciate it.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe considered using the Unity2Eclipse plugin in the Asset Store?